# How to store separate constant class for constant variables in Android development

Tags: java, android, variables, constants

I have constant variables in Android app like below. I want to move them to a separate constant class so it will be cleaner. What do you suggest? What kind of file do I create in project and do I simply import that constant class in MainActivity class? What I am looking for is similar to constants.h file in C++. What do you guys suggest?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


public static final String NET_SALE = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE1";
public static final String SER_CHRG = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE2";
public static final String TRN_IN = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE3";
public static final String TRN_OUT = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE4";
public static final String POOL = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE5";
public static final String RADIO = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE6";
```

Comment: Instead of public, set them as `protected`. Then call them everywhere in your code (even other activities or classes) like `MainActivity.NET_SALE` You might want to create a separate Java Class, instead using MainActivity.

Comment: My suggestion, create a constant file for each project and paste the constants related to the project in this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store them in a file with a class that just has `public static final` variables and use `import static com.example.Constants.*` to access them.

However, I suggest storing anything that is presented to the user in strings.xml, so that they can be translated.

Comment: these variables won't be presented to user. They will be used for calculation. So I created another class called Constants.java and following is the content of it.

`package com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.app;

public class Constants {
    public static final String NET_SALE = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE1";
    public static final String SER_CHRG = "com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE2";
...`

And this is how i imported it but it didn't work.
`import com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.app.Constants;`

Error message is "Can not find symbol variable" in Main Activity class.

Comment: @fcukinyahoo please reread my answer, you need to include 'static', and you need the '.*' part.

Comment: worked thank you. i have two questions to learn better. 1. why static needed. 2. why * in Constants.* needed? Thank you

Comment: did you see my previous comment?

Comment: @fcukinyahoo This should tell everything: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import

Answer (score 3):

The common solution is to create a class `Constants` in which you can put your constants making them `public static final`. You should also make this class not-instantiable because it just makes sense for it to be instantiated. So you can make its constructor `private`.

One more solution commonly used is to create an interface that your class can implement. 
Like this - `interface Constants` and your class - `mainActivity implements Constants`. Generally it's considered to be not very good solution, as interfaces are usually used to show class behaviour. You can refer to more info to `Effective Java` - item 19.

Answer (score 1):

Or i would suggest enumerations:

```
public enum Message{

  NET_SALE("com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE1"),
  SER_CHRG("com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE2"),
  TR_IN("com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE3"),
  TR_OUT("com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE4"),
  POOL("com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE5"),
  RADIO("com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.MESSAGE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My question would be: Where are these constants used? If they're only used within MainActivity, then that's where they should remain. If they're used in multiple locations (which it doesn't look like they are -- are they keys for Intent extras?) then you should look into seeing if it makes sense to have some base class with those values (`protected`) and just inherit from that class to pass them down.

If you're just using these to provide extras and don't want to have to make them public, you could use a static factory method to create a new Intent to start the Activity, providing the extras internally, and make those constants `private`:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context ctx, String netSale, String serChrg, String trnIn,
                               String trnOut, String pool, String radio) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NET_SALE, netSale);
    intent.putExtra(SER_CHRG, serChrg);
    intent.putExtra(TRN_IN, trnIn);
    intent.putExtra(TRN_OUT, trnOut);
    intent.putExtra(POOL, pool);
    intent.putExtra(RADIO, radio);
    return intent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Constants** in java are generally declared to be **public**, **static** and **final**.
So we will define all the constants in a final class as follows:

```
public final class AppConstants {

public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String NAME = "name";

 // inner class
 public final class LANGUAGE {
    public static final String ENGLISH = "en";
    public static final String ARABIC = "ar";

    private LANGUAGE() {
    }
}

// private constructor to block initialisation
private AppConstants() {}

}
```

Access the constant values as for example :

- **AppConstants**.ADDRESS,   // directly from Appconstants class
- **AppConstants**.EMAIL,
- **AppConstants.LANGUAGE**.ENGLISH,  // from Appconstants's inner class Language
- **AppConstants.LANGUAGE**.ARABIC.

Hope it helps someone!