# How to get String in a non activity class?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android app developement.I did found questions related to my issue but none provide the correct solution.
Here is my code where i am trying get string. I am getting error like this

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getString(int)' on a null object reference

```
public class CommonUtils {
    private static Context _context;

    public CommonUtils(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }
    public static String convertTimeToHoursMinutesString(long lTimeinMillis){
        // Calculate hours first.
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(lTimeinMillis);
        lTimeinMillis -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
        // Calculate minutes then.
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(lTimeinMillis);
        lTimeinMillis -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
        // Calculate seconds last.
        //long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(lTimeinMillis);

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(64);
        str.append(hours);

        str.append(_context.getString(R.string.Hour));
        str.append(minutes);
        str.append(_context.getString(R.string.Min));
        //str.append(seconds);
        //str.append(" Seconds");
        return(str.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getString Outside of a Context or Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253328/getstring-outside-of-a-context-or-activity)

Comment: Where is the code where you are calling `getString()` ? At which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: No..it only supports sytem resources..i have string.xml and i need to get that string in my class. @leopal

Comment: I have edited code.Please have a look at it. @gprathour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue which you are getting is `NullPointerException` on `_context`.

I think it is because you have declared `_context` as `static` variable and `convertTimeToHoursMinutesString` as `static` method.

But you are initializing the `_context` in constructor.

```
public CommonUtils(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}
```

But as the method is static so you would not be creating an object to call it. Instead you would be calling it directly by class name, like `CommonUtils.convertTimeToHoursMinutesString`. So the constructor never gets called, hence `_context` is null.

If you want to keep it static then you can do it like this,

```
public static String convertTimeToHoursMinutesString(Context _context, long lTimeinMillis){
    // Calculate hours first.
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(lTimeinMillis);
    lTimeinMillis -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
    // Calculate minutes then.
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(lTimeinMillis);
    lTimeinMillis -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
    // Calculate seconds last.
    //long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(lTimeinMillis);

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(64);
    str.append(hours);

    str.append(_context.getString(R.string.Hour));
    str.append(minutes);
    str.append(_context.getString(R.string.Min));
    //str.append(seconds);
    //str.append(" Seconds");
    return(str.toString());
}
```

Also you can access `getString()` like `context.getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING);`

Comment: Is there any way to initialize string array by using (R.string.thatvalue) ???

Comment: @JasmineAntony Check this, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4161256/1055241

Comment: I want to initialize in my enum class eg..public enum WorkStateEnums {
 WORK_EMPTY_CAR(000, "WORK_EMPTY_CAR", R.string.xyz);}

Comment: @JasmineAntony Try it out first, if you face any issues first try to understand it and fix it yourself, if it doesn't work then you can post a new question here.

Comment: Hi i am getting NullPointerException  (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference)

Comment: @JasmineAntony Hello, I think that we solved that day, when you posed this question.

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
str.append(_context.getString(R.string.Min));
```

please replace it with

```
str.append(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.Min));
```