# How can i return string resource in function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this extension-function:

```
fun Int.convertToTextual(): String =
    when {
        (this > 337.5) -> "N"
        (this > 292.5) -> "N-W"
        (this > 247.5) -> "W"
        (this > 202.5) -> "S-W"
        (this > 157.5) -> "S"
        (this > 122.5) -> "S-E"
        (this > 67.5) -> "E"
        (this > 22.5) -> "N-E"
        else -> "N"
    }
```

I need it to return my strings from resources instead of just strings. How can i do it? `getString` doesn't work :(

Comment: `getString` doesn't work because it needs `context`, lots of resources available for this online

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getString Outside of a Context or Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253328/getstring-outside-of-a-context-or-activity)

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I will mark your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change Int to Double. Because You need to set an extension function for a decimal number.

```
fun Double.convertToTextual(context:Context): String =
    when {
        (this > 337.5) -> context.getString(R.string.code)
        (this > 292.5) -> "N-W"
        (this > 247.5) -> "W"
        (this > 202.5) -> "S-W"
        (this > 157.5) -> "S"
        (this > 122.5) -> "S-E"
        (this > 67.5) -> "E"
        (this > 22.5) -> "N-E"
        else -> "N"
    }
```